# Caldera Forms (Wordpress) - Handling of Duplicate matching rules

Tags: wordpress, duplicate-contacts, caldera-forms

Does anyone know what duplicate matching rules are applied when a contact registers on a website using Caldera Forms to capture the contact details?
When using creating a profile in CiviCRM which can used accessed via shortcode in Wordpress to present the profile as form on your website, we can specify tell CiviCRM what to do when a duplicate match is encountered from these 3 options:

1. Issue warning and do not save
2. Update the matching contact
3. Allow duplicate contact to be created

I want to have the ability to do the same with Caldera Forms. In particular, I want to be able to allow a duplicate contact to be created for a specific use case for our organization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dedupe rules are set in the contact processor. If you want it to create a duplicate, create a dedupe rule in Civi that it can never satisfy. A dummy one basically :)

[image: Caldera Dedupe Rules]